# Building Flash Movie Dynamicaly with Jpgs/png

Tags: flash

I would like to create a flash movie dynamically with jpgs and other data on server. Is there any server side software that does this?

Comment: Could you clearly state what you are attempting to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [swftools](http://www.swftools.org/). Here is an example:

```
$ jpeg2swf -o movie.swf -3 1 -X 640 -Y 480 -f -z *.jpg
```

to create a movie out of all the JPEG files in the directory.

Another option is to use the Perl module [SWF::Builder](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/SWF::Builder).

Comment: Thanks.. I think this may help.

Answer (score 0):

PHP comes with the [Ming library](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.ming.php). It's fairly basic, but it should do what you need (create a series of SWFBitmap objects, adding each one to a new frame of a SWFMovie.